# What is "traditional style of param serialization' in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Do you know what is "traditional style of param serialization" for jQuery.ajax() as mentioned in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ?

Can you give some introduction?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the link provided in that comment? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [`jQuery.param()`:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param)

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `$.param()` method serializes deep objects recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`.

Given

```
var p = {foo: [1,2,3], bar: 42};
```

setting `traditional` to `true` generates

```
foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&bar=42
```

While e.g. Python can handle these parameters, i.e. it generates a list for `foo`, PHP will only consider the last `foo` parameter.

But now by default, the result of the serialization is (actually it is URI encoded)

```
foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3&bar=42
```

which can be better handled, as mentioned, by PHP and RoR.

---

Or maybe even more interesting is this. Given:

```
var p = {foo: {1: [3,4], 2:2,3:3}, bar: 42};
```

traditional produces:

```
foo=[object Object]&bar=42
```

which is clearly not useful in comparison with the "new" way:

```
foo[1][]=3&foo[1][]=4&foo[2]=2&foo[3]=3&bar=42
```

Comment: I'm using Cherrypy as backend. I don't see any documentation instructing how to handle it manually, it's all seem to be automatic. Do you suggest using `traditional = true` all the time with Python? Thanks.