# passing array from javascript to controller MVC 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using razor and I'm having a hard time passing an array to a controller. the array contains objects that I made and I am trying to do this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "HomePage/HandleOperations",
     data: JSON.stringify(operationCollection),
     success: function (data) { alert("SUCESS");},
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json"
});
```

and my controller is:

```
 public void HandleOperations(List<string> operationCollection)
 {

 }
```

I am not required to use ajax but I am not sure how else it could be done. In the controller it shows that the "operationCollection" contains elements but they are all null.

Comment: Side note - You don't need to call JSON.stringify, jQuery (or XHR2) will do this for you.

Comment: did you try adding `traditional: true` to your ajax options?

Comment: still same problem, it shows the right number of elements but they are all null

Comment: Have you tried with string[] instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "HomePage/HandleOperations",
     data: {operations: operationCollection},
     success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});
```

and declare a class server side like this:

```
public class Operation
{
  public int Index;
  public string Source;
  public string Target;
  public int AddOrDel;
}
```

then you can have this action:

```
public void HandleOperations(Operation[] operations)
{
}
```

Comment: this works! I did not know that I need a model for it. Thanks

Comment: Well, need and need, you will get the opportunity to put words on the items, they are after all operations :)

Comment: In the json version, you keep the call to JSON.Stringify, and dataType: "json" and have an action that takes a string as parameter, public void HandleOperations(string operations), then you call var operationArr = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Operation>(operations);, you need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions to your project

Comment: you actually dont need a model, using traditional:true will do it in ajax post.

Answer (score 11):

the Ajax parameter

```
traditional : true
```

will do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean? Where should I write traditional??

Comment: $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "HomePage/HandleOperations",
     data: {operations: operationCollection},
     traditional: true,
     success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});

Answer (score 4):

Usage of the traditional: true parameter for an ajax call:

To help radbyx, using the "traditional: true" property of an ajax call, like the following, will tell ajax to use the traditional form of serialization. More details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
 or [What is "traditional style of param serialization' in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery).

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "HomePage/HandleOperations",
     data: {operations: operationCollection},
     traditional: true,
     success: function (data) { alert("SUCCESS"); }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add "traditional:true" parameter in your ajax.

**Example:**

```
var parentValueToPush=new Array();
$('[name=SelectedUsers]:checked').each(function () {
            parentValueToPush.push($(this).val());
            temp.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: //URL,
            type: 'get',
            traditional: true,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            data: { SelectedUsers: parentValueToPush},
            success: function (data) {
                   //Result
            }
        });
```