# Partial View not rendered from controller? WHY?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial

This is in accordance to my question:

**[How to pass array created from jQuery to controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613184/how-to-pass-array-created-from-jquery-to-controller-method)**

Here is my controller returning a partial view:

```
     public ActionResult PartialViewChild(int id)
     {
    //stmts /*model is assigned here */
    return PartialView("ChildPartialView", model);
     }
```

My problem now is that, the view returned from my controller action is not rendered by `$.ajax()` call. I had put a debugger in the success function, it never hit there. So, by chance, I added a error function also in ajax call like,

```
        var id=currentSelected.Id;
        $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("PartialViewChild", "ControllerChild")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({id : id}),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
        $("#id1").html(result);
        },
         error: function (data, errorThrown) {
         alert('request failed :' + errorThrown);
         }});
```

I also found out that, the div with id "id1" must be empty for the partial view to be rendered correctly. But, that div at the start renders a EmptyView like,

```
       <div id="id1">
       @{Html.RenderPartial("ChildPartialView", new ChildPartialModel());}        
       </div>
```

and based on the ajax call, I wanted to fill in that div with the returned result (by now all the attributes will have value)..
But, unfortunately, here I only had the alert of error:() from ajax call telling me that there was a "Parse error".

Can someone tell me how can I correct it?

**EDIT:**

This is my Partial View:

```
    @model Models.ChildColumnsModel
    <div>
    <span>@Html.LabelFor(c => c.Phone_Number):</span>
    <span>@Html.TextBoxFor(c=> c.Phone_Number)</span>
    </div>
    // like this it has all its attributes...
```

and in my controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult PartialViewChild(int id)
     {
     var model=child.GetReletedInfo(id); /*proper results are returned here which is of ChildColumnsModel type */
     return PartialView("ChildPartialView", model);
     }
```

Comment: Show you full partial view code.

Comment: and more about the ("ChildPartialView", model);

Comment: Try eidt var model=child.GetReletedInfo(id)?? new ChildColumnsModel();

Comment: what is the actual use of this stmt?

Comment: this stmt means : if child.GetReletedInfo(id) is null then create a new ChildColumnsModel

Comment: @user2771399 my friend, i have one last idea....write above your method [HttpPost] and tell me if this worked

Comment: whatch my edit @user2771399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SORRY ALL... I resolved the issue. I had an extra property for ajax telling its dataType: "Json"... when I removed it, All was FINE.. How silly of myself..?!! Thank you all for your VALUABLE answers and TIME friends..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

try this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChildPartialView(int id)
 {
    //stmts /*model is assigned here */
    return PartialView(model);
 }
```

Comment: Is it ok if my <div> with id "id1", already has some data as i have shown?

Comment: Sorry, NO luck. i still get the alert from error function of ajax..;'(

Comment: it doesnt matter, because its overwritting everything inside the div. but if you want to get sure try: $("#div1").empty(); and then $("#div1").html(result);

Comment: Sorry. i still dont get the result back from controller into my div..;'(

Comment: did you rebuild the solution xD (sorry might be)