# Post an empty array using ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I was trying to post an empty array using ajax call, but the data is posted as an empty string i.e. Parts: . I want the data to be posted as Parts:[] which is not happening because the webservice handles empty collection only ie Parts[].

```
Code:
var parts=[];
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://api-test.example.com",
dataType: "json",
headers:{Authorization:authHeader},
data: "Parts="+parts,
    success: function (result) {
    },
error: function (result){
}
});
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: most probably you should handle this on the server side, what is the underlying technology for your webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass data as  data : {}

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://api-test.example.com",
dataType: "json",
headers:{Authorization:authHeader},
data: {Parts : parts} ,
    success: function (result) {
    },
error: function (result){
}
});
```

Comment: I have tried the same, but still not working, parts is considered as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Set below property to your call,

```
 'traditional': true
```

also edit your JSON data pass as,

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ "parts" : parts } );
```

Actually, All previous versions used to pass arrays by this way,  but as new frameworks ruby on rails and others process arrays differently jQuery started new approach.

More help on SO is as below,

[What is "traditional style of param serialization' in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery)

Comment: On setting traditional as true also gave me the same result as an empty string.

Comment: Whats your variable name at server side which is mapped with Parts?

Comment: Try adding   data: JSON.stringify({ "parts" : parts } );

Comment: The .net webservice accepts Parts:[] when parts is null; and i am trying to json.stringify but it is passed as an empty string Parts: [] and parts is getting added to the list in the service side. Any help

Answer (score 0):

As the "traditional: true" was not working for me, i found an other solution : setting the array to null.

```
let myArray = [];

// whatever code

if(myArray == [])
  myArray = null;
```