# Rails / Coffeescript, data in array not being passed property

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Have the following Ajax request:

```
data = {foo: {id: 1}, 
        array: [
                {id: 2, date: "Jan  1, 2015", quantity: 100}
               ]}

$.ajax "/api/foo",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON"
  data: data,
  success: (data) ->
    console.log(data)
```

The issue is that the server gets the following params:

```
{foo: {id: 1}, 
 array: { 
         0:{id: 2, date: "Jan  1, 2015", quantity: 100}
 }}
```

As you can see the array is transformed into a hash with incremental keys. Why isn't the data being received as I sent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) this is the expected behavior.

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

You can play with the `traditional` setting that is [mentioned in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to try to get the exact same representation though you should be able to use this as it is.

In your controller, you should be able to do the following `params[:array][0]` or `params[:array].each ...` to access the data. You're still getting a response that Ruby can handle like an array. If there were more records in this array it would look like this.

```
array: { 
  0:{id: 2, date: "Jan  1, 2015", quantity: 100}
  1:{id: 3, date: "Jan  1, 2015", quantity: 200}
  2:{id: 4, date: "Jan  1, 2015", quantity: 300}
}
```

Comment: The end point is accessed via multiple methods and I wanted to have a standardized format. Thus I'm trying to get the array to pass properly.

Comment: Understandable. [This stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery) explains the second link in my answer. Let me know if setting `traditional = true` works.

Comment: Traditional = true doesn't work, these are the params the server receives: {"foo"=>"[object Object]", "array"=>"[object Object]"}

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up doing something a bit hacky so both cases work.