# Passing key-value pair array to Controller action in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, key-value

I have a key-value pair through which I send down values like this:

```
   $(document).on('click', '.chkAll', function () {
        $("#tableProducts thead tr th input:checkbox").change(function () {
            $(".chkItem").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    product_ids[$(this).attr('id')] = "Checked";
                    productLocation[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('location');
                });
            } else {
                $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    delete product_ids[$(this).attr('id')];
                    delete productLocation[$(this).attr('id')];
                });
            }
        });
```

And this is how I post all the keys into the .NET MVC Action:

```
values: Object.keys(product_ids)
```

And fetching it in Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetValues(List<string> values)
{
// now I have all the keys here but now I'd like values as well...
}
```

The way I imagine this to be done is by passing down the entire name-value pair array directly into the function and then fetching it, so that then I'd have:

```
// key (product id) => 0124914815DD29
// value => checked
```

Both strings ...

I've tried by doing simply like this:

```
values: product_ids // in jquery post
```

And then fetching the value like this:

```
public ActionResult GetValues(Dictionary<string,string> values)
{
// but now the values dictionary is always empty
}
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

This is the part where the data is posted:

```
$(".btnAnalyze").click(function () {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(product_ids) == true) {
                ShowMessage("You haven't selected any product!");
                return;
            }
            else {
                var guid = '@Guid.NewGuid()'
                var postData = { values: Object.keys(product_ids), drange: $('.range').val(), ID: guid, type: $('input[name=type]:checked').val(), shipping: $('input[name=shipping]:checked').val(), condition: $('input[name=condition]:checked').val(), minprice: $('.txtmin').val(), maxprice: $('.txtmax').val(), Title: $('.txtSearch').val(), negative: $('.txtNegativeKeywords').val(),locations: productLocation };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Analyze/GetAllProducts",
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "Error") {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        } else if (data=="Ok"){
                            window.location.href = '/Analyze/Index/' + guid // redirect to another page
                        }
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true
                });
            }
        });
```

And mapped header of the Action:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetAllProducts(List<string> values, string drange, string ID, string type, string shipping, string condition, string minprice, string maxprice, string Title,string negative,string minFeedback, string maxFeedback, Dictionary<string,string> locations)
```

@Haim Please see the last parameter that I'm passing into function , that's the one I'm trying to turn into a dictionary...

Comment: Anyone guys?  I think this should work but I'm missing a slight details probably... ?

Comment: Why do you need the value if it is always "Checked" (if it's unchecked, you're already removing it from `product_ids`)?

Comment: @haim770 I'll change this value from checked to item quantity..

Comment: Please add the part where you actually post the data to the server

Comment: @haim770 I've edited my question, just like that.. =) Okay one second

Comment: Also, is `product_ids` an `Object` or `Array`?

Comment: @haim770 an array, this is how I declare it:  var product_ids = {};

Comment: What's in that `productLocation`?

Comment: @haim770 please check m updated question, I've provided contents of ProductLocation as well, it is basically a key-value pair array as well just little bit different contents..

Comment: Try to use JSON instead: `$.ajax({ data: JSON.stringify(postData), contentType: 'application/json', ... })`. Alternatively, try with `traditional: false`. The bottom line is that the data is not received in a format that the default model-binder can understand.

Comment: @haim770 ok one second

Comment: @haim770 all parameters are null now when I do JSON.Stringify...

Comment: Did you add `contentType: 'application/json'` as well? Have you tried with `traditional: false`?

Comment: @haim770 Yes I set content type to this, and haven't tried with traditional:false, I will now one moment

Comment: @haim770 tried, doesn't works :/

Comment: A okay it works with traditional = false !! =)

Comment: @haim770 do u wanna write an answer so that  I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the default model binder expects the following format when trying to bind a `Dictionary`:

```
locations[1]=val1&locations[2]=val2
```

But using jQuery's [traditional parameterization](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) you'll get the following instead:

```
locations=[object+Object]
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497151/1625737

Comment: Side note: The format you have shown only works for a `Dictionary` where the key and value are simple value types or `string`. Other wise, the format is `name[indexer].Key=value&name[indexer].Value.propertyName=value&...`