# How does jQuery's .get() encode the arguments object?

Tags: jquery

Given the code below:

```
requestRefresh("arg1", "arg2");

function requestRefresh ( listofnames ) {
        var args = {
                name:   [],
                action: "ajax.refresh"
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
                args.name.push(arguments[i]);           
        }
        jQuery.get(url, args).done(function ( results ) {
            ...
        });
});
```

The query gets encoded as:

```
url?name%5B%5D=arg1&name%5B%5D=arg2&action=ajax.refresh
```

but I want it without the encoded '[]' after each "name":

```
url?name=arg1&name=arg2&action=ajax.refresh
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior exists since 1.4. The previous behavior is what you are looking for

- Change it using  [`jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery)
- Encode it yourself and pass the string to  `$.get`
- Call `$.ajax(url, {traditional: true})` instead // Thanks to @Barmar

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

```
// <=1.3.2:
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a=2&a=3&a=4"
// >=1.4:
$.param({ a: [ 2, 3, 4 ] }); // "a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4"
```

Comment: You can also call `$.ajax` and use the `traditional: true,` option. That way you don't change the setting globally, just for that request.

Comment: @JohnHascall It's the way most scripting languages expect multiple parameters with the same name to be submitted. If you don't use `[]` they only make the last value available to the application.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up changing the receiving framework to accept `a[]=2&a[]=3&a[]=4` (it previously accepted only `a=2&a=3&a=4` or `a[0]=2&a[1]=3&a[2]=4`).  It seemed far preferable to telling people you need to do some funny business on the jQuery-side.

Comment: @JohnHascall Yes, that format is more popular then just the `a=2&a=3` except in the Java world, I believe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection/13592324#13592324