# What is use of traditional and cache in Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new in Ajax I am using this following ajax call for call my controller:

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "get",
                        url: "getUser",
                        cache: false,
                        traditional: true,
                        data: {'jsonData': JSON.stringify(selectedDataArray)},
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (response) {
}
```

But here I want to understand what is use of traditional and cache any help?

Comment: Please refer the link : [Ajax documentation for more details](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Reference:
  https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

cache : A Boolean value indicating whether the browser should cache the requested pages. Default is true.

traditional :A Boolean value specifying whether or not to use the traditional style of param serialization.

Please visit below mention link to get more understating on term "traditional style of param serialization"

[What is "traditional style of param serialization' in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497093/what-is-traditional-style-of-param-serialization-in-jquery)